# Left join with sub query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Not sure why its throwing an error at t2. I am trying to run a simple sql query.
Running on MS-SQL and the error message says 'incorrect syntax near t2'

```
UPDATE t1

SET t1.EmpSubCompetency = t2.EmpSubCompetency,
    t1.Competency = t2.Competency,
t1.FileName = t2.FileName,
t1.Longitude = t2.Longitude,
t1.Latitude = t2.Latitude,
t1.SubAreaName = t2.Region,
t1.SectorTag=t2.SectorTagClassification

FROM dbo.STG_MyCompetencies t1

LEFT JOIN (select * from dbo.STG_EmployeeMaster where Act_Flg='Y') t2
```

Comment: If it throws an error, why not include the error message in the question?

Comment: The `ON` clause is missing

Comment: Also, which DBMS are you using? MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the missing `ON` clause.  Further, you don't need a subquery for this logic:

```
FROM dbo.STG_MyCompetencies t1 LEFT JOIN
     dbo.STG_EmployeeMaster t2
     ON t1.??? = t2.??? AND
        em.Act_Flg = 'Y'
```

Note that unmatched rows will have all the columns set to `NULL`.

The `???` is for whatever column should be used for the `JOIN`.

Comment: this works fine. Thanks. Just checking, is it always better to avoid sub queries whenever we can?

Comment: @curious_learner . . . You shouldn't make a query more complicated than necessary.  The subquery is unnecessary.